# How to compare two samples without knowledge of the distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing

lets say I have the mean of two different measurements of something, a and b. I also have the standard deviation on a, and b, but I do not have access to all the individual measurements of a and b. Is it possible to compare the two values to see if the means are statistically different (i.e., reject the null hypothesis that they are the same)? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you know the sample sizes of sets $a$ and $b$?

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to put that information in. I do know how many samples were used to calculate it.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it I do not really know the sample size. Is it possible without this piece of information?

Comment: Well, my go-to answer was Student's *t*-test, which requires the sample sizes to be known. There may exist a more clever procedure which does not require that information, but I'm afraid I'm not aware of one.

Comment: I believe a t-test also requires that the data come from a normal distribution, does it not?

Comment: @user777 You're on a good track. There's a stupid (not clever) procedure but in extreme cases it can be effective: assume the worst and suppose there were only two measurements in each group and conservatively replace the smaller SD by the larger one.  Also assume the measurements are iid Normal. If the resulting t-test identifies a difference, you have made some progress. If it is inconclusive, the results are inconclusive. Without some kind of distributional assumption (like normality), nothing can be done.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! What I like the most about talking to you is that speak with the experience of having conducted statistical consulting for several decades. Due to my age, most of my experience is of the form "well, according to this book I read...". Your replies prompt me to think about problems more creatively.

Answer (score 2):

If, as you now say, you don't know the sample sizes but you have sample means and sample standard deviations, the best you can guarantee is say that the sample sizes are at least two (since if either were smaller than two you couldn't compute standard deviations).

So you can at least test for that 'worst case' and see if there's a difference on that basis (that would be a [two-sample t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)).

[A possible alternative is to figure out which combinations of sample sizes in the two samples would imply a significant difference.]

If you know *anything* about sample sizes - lower bounds, upper bounds, likely ranges, their ratio, whatever, that information is likely to be at least somewhat useful.

---

As you suggest, the t-test relies on the normality assumption. But without the individual observations you will pretty much have to make some kind of assumption, and it's at least somewhat robust to the assumption, more so if the true sample sizes are not actually very small.

Comment: I now see whuber posted the same suggestion in comments as I was typing that answer.

Comment: The subtlety in this suggestion concerns estimating the variance of the difference of the means. That's why I suggested replacing the smaller SD by the larger in order to proceed. With some additional calculation, that could be improved upon using the "possible alternative" you describe: for all possible combinations of sample sizes, retain the one yielding the largest (most conservative) p-value. This is not an infinite search, because the p-value will eventually decrease for very large sample sizes.

Comment: @whuber I don't think there's any issue with an equal variance assumption (which we can at least compare the sample values for rough proximity as a reasonableness check). If we take a Welch-Satterthwaite approach instead, there's an issue, as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, there's definitely an issue with highly unequal SDs. But even when you use an equal-variance test, it is possible to do better with a search--but the difference will be inconsequential unless you are using very high thresholds (around $.3$ or greater) for significance. *E.g.*, take $s_1=300$ and $s_2=30$ (which are not significantly different for samples of size 2): with $n_1=2$, the p-value is slightly higher for $n_2=3$ than for $n_2=2$.

Comment: I think I finally see what you're trying to convey. I'll try to write something on it tomorrow. Have to sleep now.

Comment: @whuber I see in your example (which I didn't read as far as last night because I got the point by then) you're using a *significance test* to decide whether or not to use an equal sample assumptions. I recommend against doing that every time I see it.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear: I'm not trying to say anything about how you should decide which t-test to use. I was only pointing out in passing that *if* you wished to conduct (say) an F-test to see whether the SDs differ, you wouldn't reject the null, so I have some justification in using these SDs--even though they differ by an order of magnitude--in an example that applies an equal-variance t-test. With the value $0.3$ I was referring to the threshold of significance for the t-test itself.